# dynamic array C doesn't work for all inputs

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to do matrix chain multiplication and I need to take input from a file in C

It works fine for one test case while for other run fails

testcase #1 (this works fine)

```
3 5
5 7
7 9
9 6
6 7
7 9
```

testcase #2 (this gives matrix.exe stopped working)

```
30 35
35 15
15 5
5 10
10 20
20 25
```

NOTE: In testcases consecutive numbers are rows and columns of matrices

This is the code I'm using

```
int *p,i=0;
char str[3],*extra;
FILE * file;
file = fopen("D:/Dump/testcases/matrix.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", str)!=EOF){
        switch(i){
            case 0:     p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
                        *(p)=atoi(str);
                        break;
            default:    *(p+i)=(int)malloc(sizeof(int));
                        *(p+i)=atoi(str);
                        break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - Unfortunately, what you are doing is *wrong*.  Q: What are you *trying* to do?  Does each line in "matrix.txt"  contain data for an entire matrix?  How do you know how big the matrix is?  EXAMPLE: for a 3x3 matrix, you'll need something like: `p = (int *)malloc (3 * 3 * sizeof(int))`

Comment: The file doesn't actually contain matrix data. It contains n lines for n matrices and each line has 2 integers 1 is for no of rows and the other for columns

Unless I read the whole file, I won't know how many matrices are there

Comment: is this homework? otherwise i would suggest using c++ and std::vector or similar

Comment: Yes, This is homework and I need to do it in C. I seriously don't understand why it's working once and failing the next time

Comment: you can't alloc memory like that, there is nothing to say that *(p + i) isn't already filled and used by something else, you will have to store the size of the matrix in the file (n, m) and pre-allocate n*m, or use a dynamic array that grows

Comment: Could you tell me what a dynamic array is? That would be helpful, Ion Todirel

Comment: look at std::vector, C standard library does not have collections, so if you are writing C code, you can either make/use a linked list or make a dynamic array (array + the management to relocate once there isn't enough space) yourself

Comment: additionally you can read the file twice, once for counting the elements, and the second pass to read them in

Comment: "This is homework and I need to do it in C. I seriously don't understand why it's working once and failing the next time – Sai Teja Reddy" - it's because you incorrectly allocating memory assuming *(p + i) is yours to take, but your code might have other problems, try using a debugger

Comment: I can read the file twice but my homework is to convert the c code into assembly language and optimize it. It's not a really good idea.

Comment: You don't need to create a special case for `i == 0`; use the same code as for the other case.  This avoids code duplication.  Your test for `sscanf()` is sub-optimal; you should compare `!= 1` since you can get 0 returned in general (though with `%s` you're probably reasonably safe).  There is room to think using `%2s` would be a good idea; any three-digit number would cause trouble.

Comment: You have serious problems in understanding what your assignment is and how it is supposed to work. You should first revise your course work on dynamic allocation and file handling. It makes not much sense to ask here to get information on particular bits of information.

Answer (score 2):

So many problems and misconceptions; it is hard to provide useful advice.

As I understand it, you are meant to be reading the dimensions of a series of matrices with two numbers per line of input, and the second number in line N should be the same as the first number in line N+1.  You don't know until you reach EOF how many lines of input there will be.  Generally, the numbers should all be one or two digits (not longer).  The actual data for the arrays is stored elsewhere, or generated — it is not handled in this code.

Your code is:

```
int *p,i=0;
char str[3],*extra;
FILE * file;
file = fopen("D:/Dump/testcases/matrix.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", str)!=EOF){
        switch(i){
            case 0:     p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
                        *(p)=atoi(str);
                        break;
            default:    *(p+i)=(int)malloc(sizeof(int));
                        *(p+i)=atoi(str);
                        break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

- The file opening is OK; you don't show the close, but that's a minor issue.
- You don't limit the size of the string that is read; you could use `%2s` to ensure you do not overflow the (rather short) string you use.
- You don't check that `fscanf()` actually read 1 item.  With a character string, that's OK.  If you were reading integers directly, that would not be OK.  You could get 0 integers converted, which is neither EOF nor 1.  You should be using `while (fscanf(file, "%2s", str) == 1)`.
- There's no very obvious reason not to have `fscanf()` do the conversion for you.
- OTOH, you cannot force `fscanf()` to require two numbers (only) on a single line either; it will be happy to have all the numbers on a single line, or each number on a line on its own with 2 blank lines between each line containing numbers.
- The `switch` is a bit odd.  The `default` clause should probably be using `realloc()` rather than `malloc()`, and the cast in the `default` is seriously problematic.  The memory allocation scheme as a whole is very flawed, which you knew because you asked the question.  You could just about rescue it by writing:

  ```
  default:
      p = (int *)realloc(p, (i+1) * sizeof(int));
      p[i] = atoi(str);  /* Or *(p+i) if you prefer */
      break;
  ```

Overall, I think you need to think in terms of reading a line at a time (`fgets()`), then parsing the lines with `sscanf()`.  You should probably think in terms of allocating the array two integers at a time.

```
int  *p = 0;
int   i = 0;
FILE *file = fopen("D:/Dump/testcases/matrix.txt", "r");

if (file != 0)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != 0)
    {
        int d1, d2;
        char c;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%c", &d1, &d2, &c) != 3 || c != '\n')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Badly formatted line: %s", buffer);
            break;
        }
        void *space;
        if (i == 0)
            space = malloc(2 * (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
        else
            space = realloc(p, 2 * (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
        if (space == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed (%d bytes)\n", 2 * (i + 1) * sizeof(int));
            break;
        }
        p = (int *)space;
        p[2*i + 0] = d1;
        p[2*i + 1] = d2;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

/* i is the number of lines read (sets of matrix dimensions) */
/* p is the pointer to 2*i array dimensions */
/* ...Use i and p... */
free(p);
```

The code does not check that the second dimension on one line is the same as the first dimension on the next line.  It does not check for positive integers of 1 or 2 digits (basically, 1..99); it allows bigger values, zeroes and negative values.  (The test `c == '\n'` ensures that there's a newline after the second number; no trailing blanks etc allowed.)

Given that `p` is (now) initialized to 0 (a null pointer), you could do without the `malloc()` and simply use `realloc()` unconditionally.  Most people prefer not to do that, but it avoids repetition.